multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result
I am on python 3.9.7, and my code looks like this:
results = pool.starmap(self._process_data, zip(self.args_list,repeat(single_term)))

My full stack trace is
  File "C:\Users\simja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 372, in starmap
return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
 File "C:\Users\simja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 771, in get
raise self._value
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '<multiprocessing.pool.ExceptionWithTraceback object at 0x00000189D38AD430>'. Reason: 'NotImplementedError()'

I haven't been able to isolate a small example of this to share here. The code runs fine for about 5-10 mins and then hits this issue.
One this I found is MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '<multiprocessing.pool.ExceptionWithTraceback object at 0x0000018F09F334A8>'
but I don't like this, I need multiprocessing for real parallelism, which I won't get with multithreading.
Any ideas what I can do about this?

Can you share any details about your code? It's hard to figure it out otherwise.
